# What should I do in case of a cross site request forgery attack?

Tags: php, session, csrf

I’m trying to prevent CSRF attacks. I’ve stored a random value in the session and in the form. When processing the form, I compare the two values.
If the session and the form value aren’t equal, should I kill the script or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If this is very unlikely to happen from a real user, then I would prevent the script from saving/returning any data, but I would return a 'success' message as if it had worked. If you return a failure, it helps hackers to work out how your validation is coded.

On the other hand, if this happens to real users, I would return a friendly error, and possibly ask them to log in again.

Comment: @Jason4Ever What did you decide to do in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just let it fail. There is no point in recovering such errors.

What you should do however is also write a log entry to audit potential exploit attempts:

```
syslog(LOG_ERR, "CSRF token mismatch ...");
die("Request failed. (Disabled cookies?) Contact administrator: ...");
```

Include a humd-readable message in case it was really a browser error or something. But don't expose that it was the CSRF token that failed.

Comment: good , i do this ofcours , but the problem is lot of times this problem occure because token value change when session timeout or when user open new tab ! so it start new session with new token value ! , so i'm not sure if the action is attacker of normal person !!

Comment: Well okay. That's an entirely different question. Edit your original post to reflect that. -- In any case, then it's best if you use a CSRF token array. `$_SESSION["csrf"][] = $new_token` and for checking `in_array($_POST["csrf"], $_SESSION["csrf"])`. Regarding the session timeouts, there is nothing you can do. But that's not a common problem anyway.